# Permanently Disable a button on a button click

Tags: android

I have been trying to disable a button completely (even when the app is closed).

I have been trying to disable a button completely (even when the app is closed) using shared preference and it worked. However, I accidentally deleted the file and cannot get it to work again. I have looked at the examples from the same question but it does not work for me.

```
com.example.new.app;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPreferences spStateButton;
SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;
int clickcount=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    final Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    spStateButton= getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Button_State", 0);
    spEditor = spStateButton.edit();


    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(passWord.getText().toString().equals("123456")) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setComponent(new ComponentName(MainActivity.this,Unlocked.class));
                startActivity(i);

            }else{
                passWord.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                clickcount=clickcount+1;

            }if (clickcount==5){
                        setButtonState(false);

        }
    };

        public void setButtonState(boolean enabled) {
            spEditor.putBoolean("btn_state", enabled);
            loginButton.setEnabled(getButtonState());

            spEditor.commit();
        }

        public boolean getButtonState(){
            return spStateButton.getBoolean("btn_state", true);
        }



    });
```

}}

Comment: I know that this is a duplicate but none of the solutions worked for me

Comment: and the code above is my MainActivity

Comment: Can you show stacktrace?

Comment: my stacktrace is long so i pasted it in a word doc

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ACo19aYR1dRww8Lna5T8unS034Nz6ckbFkV9wYHWdjw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If(isDisabled()){
button.setEnabled(false);}
isDisabled(){
// get state from shrdPref
}
```

Comment: I just replaced setButtonState(false);

Comment: with button.setEnabled(false)

Answer (score 2):

Your state is not committed so you are working with old value. You are committing after setting button state. You can reuse the value you are setting your next button state

```
public void setButtonState(boolean enabled) {
    spEditor.putBoolean("btn_state", enabled);
    loginButton.setEnabled(enabled);

    spEditor.commit();
}
```

You asked for explanation:

1. You are setting a new value of `btn_state` in shared preferences editor
2. You want to read that value from shared preferences (`spStateButton.getBoolean("btn_state", true);`) but it's not there yet because you haven't committed it.
3. You are committing value/writing value to shared preferences this is executed async.

Comment: I am not good at coding so could you please explain this to me

Comment: @DavidKim basically you are reading from preferences which were not yet updated

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to call `loginButton.setEnabled(getButtonState());` when the app starts. Also, you need to move the `setButtonState` and `getButtonState` out of the onCreate() method.

Here is the correct MainActivity:

```
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences spStateButton;
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor;
    int clickcount = 0;

    Button loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        spStateButton = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Button_State", 0);
        spEditor = spStateButton.edit();

        loginButton.setEnabled(getButtonState()); // You forgot it :)

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (passWord.getText().toString().equals("123456")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setComponent(new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, Unlocked.class));
                    startActivity(i);

                } else {
                    passWord.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    clickcount = clickcount + 1;

                }
                if (clickcount == 5) {
                    setButtonState(false);

                }
            }

        });
    }

    public void setButtonState(boolean enabled){
        spEditor.putBoolean("btn_state", enabled);
        loginButton.setEnabled(getButtonState());

        spEditor.commit();
    }

    public boolean getButtonState() {
        return spStateButton.getBoolean("btn_state", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: when I do this, it says "cannot resolve method getButtonState()"

Comment: You have also to move the setButtonState and getButtonState out of the onCreate() method. See the updated code.

Comment: when I start the app, the button is disabled before even clicking 5 times.

Comment: Yes, that is because you have pressed 5 times before, and the value of sharedpreferences has been changed to false. Try to reinstall the app (uninstall first) in order to restore the click count.